# Is there any pre-defined class in .net 2.0 to hold a single generic-typed mutable field?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mutable

In a number of my projects, I find myself declaring a rather boring class:

```
    Class Holder(Of T)
        Public It As T
        Sub New(ByVal It As T)
            Me.It = It
        End Sub
    End Class
```

to e.g. allow an object to give information to another object in such a way that the information can be mutated later wherever it goes.  For example, in a Dictionary(Of String, Holder(Of SomeImmutableType)) it's possible to update the thing of SomeImmutableType without having to change the Dictionary itself (since the Dictionary's entry for a given key will always contain the same Holder object, that Holder object may be used as a lock).

Is there any built-in class which would be more suitable for this purpose?  I'd prefer .net 2.0 compatibility, but even in 4.0 the Tuple type is immutable.  If there isn't such a thing built in, is it better for each type that needs a Holder type to define it itself as a nested type, or require that there be one definition of Holder within a project?

The only built-in thing I'm aware of would be Array.  Using an array of one element would work, but it feels really icky, since generally when code has an array there's an expectation that it will be usable with some size other than one.

**PS**--Usage examples:

1. To count how many times each different string appears within a list, one can create a Dictionary(Of String, Holder(Of Integer)) and then for each string, do a TryGetValue to retrieve the holder if any already exists.  If none exists, create a new holder and store it in the dictionary.  Then in either case increment the value stored in the holder.  Note that doing things this way will require a minimum number of dictionary writes.

   If one has a dictionary of immutable things, and one wishes to change the value associated with a key to a derivation of the old value, (e.g. it's a dictionary of "String,String" and one wishes to effectively perform "MyDict(myKey) = myDict(key) & someThing"), performing such an operation by writing the dictionary would require locking the entire dictionary while one did the string append.  Probably not too bad if the operation is as simple as a string append, but potentially bad if the operation is more complex.  Using "Holder", one only need lock the Dictionary while fetching the key; one can then release the Dictionary lock and lock the Holder, allowing other threads to use the Dictionary.

   In generating closures, a compiler could use a Holder class to avoid having delegates keep alive fields that they're not going to use.  If a scope contains ExpensiveObject 
   'foo' and integer 'bar', and it contains a short-lived closure that requires both 'foo' and 'bar', and a long-lived one that just requires 'bar', the compiler could define separate closure types for the two closures, and have both of them include a reference to the same Holder(Of Bar).  This would allow closure semantics to be maintained without having to keep alive any extra objects.

Comment: I think this code may summon Cthulu. Be cautious.

Comment: Can you explain how you use it?  I am guessing you want a bunch of places in code to use a particular instance of your T object and you need to be able to update the reference to a different immutable object.  The thing is that updating the reference may have consistency implications in a multi-threaded environment.  If there are references to `holder.It` throughout a method, someone can change the value of `It`, so half of your method uses the old instance, and the second half uses the new instance.

Comment: @agent-j: Obviously if one has a reference to a Holder(Of T) there's the possibility that something else may change it, as could occur with any logic.  If anything, the use of a Holder(Of T) makes things far more explicit than they are with e.g. the pass-by-reference closures Microsoft uses (where what look like local variables can get changed by other threads if they get a copy of a closure which mutates them).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any type that does what you want.

Regarding your three usage cases:

1. Sure, but keep in mind that you are now trading increased collection pressure, increased virtual memory usage, and lots of additional time to trace the living object set for decreased number of stores of integers into dictionary buckets. Is that a good tradeoff?  Doesn't sound that great to me. I would be surprised if this were a large win.
2. Sounds like a complicated solution. There are other solutions. For example, you could write an access layer on top of the dictionary that transforms the value as desired without ever mutating the dictionary.
3. The key is "the compiler could make two closure types". The problem you are describing is a result of the fact that we do not partition the closure types effectively. The closure class is essentially your "holder" type, just holding on to arbitrarily many data, not just one.  (We are considering going with a better solution for partitioning closure types in C# and VB, but no promises.)

All that said, I have used your trick before, mostly for situations where I am porting existing code from C++ that makes heavy use of passing around references to variables. I typically use this kind of trick to get the ported code up and running, and then refactor it into something a bit more idiomatically C#-ish later.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, what's the collection pressure? :)

Comment: @lukas: "collection pressure" or "memory pressure" is a vague way of generalizing all the factors that the garbage collector uses when deciding when to start up another round of collection and compaction of the managed heap. Allocating lots of little heap objects is a contributor to collection pressure because the collector assumes that lots of objects might mean lots of short-lived objects that are now dead and can be cheaply collected. In many applications it is a good idea to avoid collection pressure; in many applications, it's irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, I understood collection as in LinkedList. Ten internets for you.

Comment: With regard to points #1 and #2, the actual scenarios I had were a little more complicated than what I described, but I didn't want to get into excessive detail.  For #2, how does one "transform" a string or a delegate, or how would one achieve effective "record locking" or atomic updates in a Dictionary(Of String, String) [where the value to be written should depend upon the value read]?  With a holder object, things are simple, but without one I see no good way.

Comment: As for #3, I think my points came out somewhat muddled, but I had three sub-points there: (1) A holder class would in many ways be used like a closure, which is already a common idiom; (2) closures may be arbitrarily partitioned by adding a single level of nesting (since the outer reference is immutable, it may be duplicated rather than aliased); (3) one may overcome limitations of the existing closure mechanism via the manual use of holder types, e.g. by having a routine accept a holder(of someType) by value, as opposed to accepting a someType by reference.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox<T>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549038.aspx
Does exactly what you want. It's a .NET 4 class and has an interface `IStrongBox` to allow you to use it in unknown typing cases. (e.g. you used reflection to create the dictionary of K, StrongBox but you don't know what V actually is so you can mutate them as IStrongBox elements.)

Comment: It's actually already in .NET 3.5; it's used internally by LINQ.